# The KeyPressEvent don't work

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with the `KeyPressEvent`, I need to move a `QGraphicsItem` player in my scene, but the program does not use the function `KeyPressEvent` of class `game`

File "game.h":

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include <QLayout>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QAction>
#include <QString>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <strutturaAlieni.h>
#include <naveGiocatore.h>
#include <laser.h>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class game;
}

class game : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit game(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~game();

    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);
}
```

and the cpp source

```
void game::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e){
switch(e->key())
{

    case Qt::Key_Left :{
                this->player->moveBy(-5,0);
    break;
    }
    case Qt::Key_Right :{
                this->player->moveBy(5,0);
    break;
    }
  }
 this->player->update();
}
```

and in the  mainwindow.cpp I click the play button that executes this code:

```
void MainWindow::on_Play_clicked()
{
    game *Gioco=new game;
    Gioco->show();
    Gioco->move(300,0);
 }
```

Why doesn't the `keyPressEvent` start?

Comment: If you put a `qDebug() << "key pressed";` statement instead of `this->player->moveBy(5,0);` and `this->player->moveBy(-5,0);` are these messages displayed?

Comment: the part of that code doesn't run....

Comment: What do you mean by `the part of that code doesn't run....`? Which part of the code?

Answer (score 2):

widget need to have a [focus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#focus-prop) to receive key events. See also [QApplication::focusWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusWidget)

If you taking about `QGraphicsView` then the [scene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#focusItem) is responsible for focus handling inside of `QGraphicsView`. 
See also [QGraphicsItem::setFocus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setFocus)

Comment: i add at on_Play_clicked() {   Gioco->setFocus(); } but it doesn't work.            also in the costructor of the class Game i added   scena=new  QGraphicsScene(0,0,600,700,this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scena);
    scena->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::black);
    ui->graphicsView->setFocus();         scena->setFocus();


    player=new naveGiocatore();
    scena->addItem(player);
    player->setFocus();              but it doesn't work... i'm tired.. uff

Comment: add to logs something what will print which widget has focus `QApplication::focusWidget()`. If it is your widget then it suppose to work. I'm also a bit confused what are you doing `QWidget` or `QGraphicsItem`. Worst case scenerio instal event filter on `QApplication` to catch all needed key events.